# How to restrict a CPU core to only 2 applications using Linux scheduler?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, scheduling

I would like to study the interaction between two applications on a CPU core, one is persistent application (NVM resident) and another is regular (DRAM resident). For this I want to only schedule these 2 applications on a core and nothing else. I am looking at Linux scheduler to accomplish this. Can someone please help me with a direction to achieve this? Can I achieve this using **sched** or do I need to modify the scheduler code of kernel so that scheduler does not schedule applications to the core of my interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**isolcpus** is a solution but the [linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) declares it as deprecated:

> isolcpus= [KNL,SMP,ISOL] Isolate a given set of CPUs from disturbance.
> [Deprecated - use cpusets instead]

The **cpuset** sub-system of the cgroups is preferable. A tool like [partrt](https://github.com/OpenEneaLinux/rt-tools/blob/master/partrt/partrt) is based on this principle to divide the CPU cores in two subsets: **nrt** where all the processes run and **rt** into which you can move your applications. Hence, the applications are isolated on some CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks for your help and also thanks for the typo correction :) @Rachid

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`isolcpus`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) command-line parameter of the kernel:

> This option can be used to specify one or more CPUs to isolate from the general SMP balancing and scheduling algorithms. You can move a process onto or off an "isolated" CPU via the CPU affinity syscalls or cpuset.